# Custom notification with useNotify in react-admin

Tags: react-admin

I'm using react-admin 4.0.3 and i want to replace the default notification for a custom component that i did. I am using the hook useNotify(), there are any way to do this? I can't find a way on the docs or anywhere

Answer (score 1):

It's in the documentation very clearly:

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Theming.html#notifications